# GUI doesn't appear when the python watchdog observer is running

Tags: python, pyqt4, watchdog

I have an application with GUI generated using the QtDesigner. When I use it together with the watchdog, the GUI doesn't appear, like it got stuck in an infinite while loop, even though it should use its own thread.

The draft of the GUI class is:

```
class Ui_Form(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.setupUi(self)

def setupUi(self, Form):
    gui components
    ...
    ...
```

The rest of the code:

```
class Watcher:
def __init__(self):
    self.observer = Observer()
    self.event_handler = Handler()
    self.observer.schedule(self.event_handler, path, recursive=False)
    self.observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(2)
    except:
        self.observer.stop()
        print("Error")

    self.observer.join()

class Handler(LoggingEventHandler):
@staticmethod
def on_any_event(event):
    do_sth()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
self.gui = loadUi(gui_path)
self.gui.show()

self.wd = Watcher()       
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```